# Unable to call model function from the controller

Tags: codeigniter, undefined

I am having problem with my code, as below
The error i am is as follow
**( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method Agentie_model::get_agentii_list() in C:\wamp\…controllers\fk_controller.php on line 65**

Controller:fk_controller

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->model('agentie_model');
    $this->load->model('fk_model');
}

public function add2() {
    $this->load->model('agentie_model');         

    $data['principal'] = $this->agentie_model->get_agentii_list(); //Here is the error(line 65) 
    $this->load->view('lista_agentii', $data);
}
```

Model:agentie_model

```
private $_table = "agentii";

public function get_agentii_list() {
    $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
    return $query->result();
}
```

View:lista_agentii

```
echo "Lista agentii:</br>";

foreach($principal as $list) {
   echo $list->nume_agentie;
}
```

Comment: It displays the message:     ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method Agentie_model::get_agentii_list() in C:\wamp\www\fk_test\application\controllers\fk_controller.php on line 65

Comment: Rename your filename also to `Fk_controller.php` and model file name Agentie_model.php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct(); 
   $this->db = $this->load->database('default', true); 
 }


 public function add2() 
{
$this->load->model('Agentie_model',true);         
$data['principal'] = $this->Agentie_model->get_agentii_list(); //Here     
$this->load->view('lista_agentii', $data);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks but it doesn't work.It displays the same error.

Comment: have you load the database in config ? if not , try this plz  in controller
   public function __construct()
    {
        // Call CI_Controller construct method first.
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
    }

Comment: $this->load->database();  
in the parent constructor

Comment: great , could u share the answer

Answer (score 0):

in your controller set this below

```
 function fk_controller() {
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->model('agentie_model');
         $this->load->model('fk_model');
    }

    public function add2() {
        $this->load->model('agentie_model');         

        $data['principal'] = $this->agentie_model->get_agentii_list(); //Here is the error(line 65) 
        $this->load->view('lista_agentii', $data);
    }
```

in your model view

```
  class Agentie_model extends CI_Model 
  {
      public function get_agentii_list() {
      $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
      return $query->result();
  }
}
```